# "Invalid bundle ID for container" for Core Data and CloudKit

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, visionos

I get this error even though everything is turned on. How can I solve it? It works on iOS but I get this error on visionOS:

> CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _recoverFromPartialError:forStore:inMonitor:]_block_invoke(2726): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600003b0c700>: Found unknown error as part of a partial failure: <CKError 0x600000cce460: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "Invalid bundle ID for container"; op = 7FE8CD52A7B2E8FC; uuid = D8D1F2C9-2C01-45B2-BECC-270CA5520D55; container ID = "iCloud.Multitools">

I tried the steps below and it works in iOS but not in visionOS:

```swift
let previewContainer:ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(cloudKitDatabase: .private("iCloud.Multitools")) 
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: NoteModel.self, configurations: config)
        return container
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Error to create container")
    }
}()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747259